# How to send e-mail from consumer device?

Tags: security, email, raspberry-pi, iot

What is the right way to send e-mail from an consumer product?

Say your are developing the "forgot password" functionality on an app, running on a micro computer - like the raspberrypi - that the user can buy of the shelf?

On one hand, the consumer can't be bothered to enter its own SMTP credentials. On the other hand, storing the manufacturer's SMTP credentials is a security flaw, because the hardware with physical access can be easily hacked.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build a forgot password functionality, you should build out an API on a server that you control that has the forgot password functionality. Then, you can send the email to them with the temporary reset values, and you wouldn't need to ship your SMTP credentials on their device.

Comment: It is a consumer product, like your router or media player, for example. The password is stored and verified in the hardware itself, as it needs to work without internet connection.